# How to draw control border in efficent way

Tags: c#, winforms, paint

Hi
I have my custom control on which I draw color border by overriding OnPaint method. However I would like to change the border color of my control if mouse enter the area of control and if mouse leave the control.  At first I wanted to react on event mouseLeave and mouseEnter and repaint control border with a proper color. However in my control is several textboxes,labels etc - so events mouseEnter and mouseLeave fire quite a lot of times and this causes that my control blinks (because of many redraws).

Is there any better way to find a proper moment to redraw control then  react on mouseLeave and mouseEnter  ??

Answer (score 2):

You should invalidate your control only if the mouse is over it.  You can check the position of the mouse by inspecting the static [`MousePosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx) variable, available for all controls.  Just add a check to conditionally invalidate your control.

The simplest way to do this is to perform these checks from within the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events, then invalidate appropriately.

```
protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    var mousePos = this.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(mousePos))
    {
        this.Invalidate(invalidateChildren: true);
    }
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    var mousePos = this.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    if (!this.ClientRectangle.Contains(mousePos))
    {
        this.Invalidate(invalidateChildren: true);
    }
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
}
```

For a more robust way to handle this, you need to determine whether or not the mouse actually enters or leaves your control.  You would need to keep two variables to keep state, one to tell if the mouse is currently over your control and one to tell if the mouse was over your control (since the last time checked).  If these are different, then invalidate your control.  You'll get the added bonus of knowing whether the mouse is over your control so you can perform some operations in your paint method conditionally.

```
private bool wasMouseOver;
private bool isMouseOver;
public bool IsMouseOver { get { return isMouseOver; } }
private void CheckMousePosition()
{
    var mousePos = this.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    wasMouseOver = isMouseOver;
    isMouseOver = this.ClientRectangle.Contains(mousePos);
    if (isMouseOver != wasMouseOver)
        this.Invalidate(invalidateChildren: true);
}

// then register this method to the mouse events
EventHandler mouseHandler = (sender, e) => CheckMousePosition();
MouseEnter += mouseHandler;
MouseLeave += mouseHandler;
MouseMove += (sender, e) => CheckMousePosition();
```

Comment: So should I use mouseOver event ?? but how would I konw if/when mouse left my control  (to draw default border)??

Comment: "You should invalidate your control only if the mouse is over it."  That doesn't make sense to me here.  Shouldn't you only invalidate when the mouse-over state has changed (in-->out or out-->in)?

Comment: @tron: Sorry, I left that out thinking you knew how to handle that. ;)  I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: @Justin: I figured tron was already using the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events to invalidate the controls.  So he'd invalidate by checking if the mouse was still over the control within the handlers.